# Skype Api documentation?

Tags: api, skype

I've found out through [This Java wrapper](https://github.com/Delthas/JavaSkype/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/delthas/skype/WebConnector.java). that skype has a https://api.skype.com/, and you can perform requests through it. So far i've only done /users/username/profile/avatar, through a browser. Is there some sort of documentation for this? Everything i've looked up so far has been noise

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  SO is a place for technical questions after you've tried a number of things but failed to make any progress, but it is really not the right place for research/general advice questions like this.  The Skype developer page is [here](https://www.skype.com/en/developer/).  I don't know, but the Software Engineering exchange, or Reddit, might be more appropriate places for this question.  Good luck!

Comment: @MaxvonHippel thanks, but skype's page is a bunch of noise to me. I'll try reddit and software engineering exchange

Comment: Sure, good luck.  I understand, it's just not an appropriate question for S/O and the reality is that you are likely to be down voted.  S/O is a very good place to ask questions, but not *all* questions.  That said, check back often and you'll eventually end up asking a question where you do get helpful answers.  In the mean time, try exploring [the sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/downloadrunsamples), and see if the comments in the code maybe explain things better than the official docs (they often do!).